# Update array content within another array that don't have key

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDB content as below:

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"57c6699711bd6a0976cabe8a"
      },
      "ID":"1111",
      "FullName":"AAA",
      "Category":[
         {
            "CategoryId":{
               "$oid":"57c66ebedcba0f63c1ceea51"
            },
            "_id":{
               "$oid":"57e38a8ad190ea1100649798"
            },
            "Value":[
               {
                  "Name":""
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "CategoryId":{
               "$oid":"57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40"
            },
            "_id":{
               "$oid":"57e38a8ad190ea1100649797"
            },
            "Value":[
               [
                  "111",
                  "XXXX",
                  "2005"
               ],
               [
                  "1212",
                  "YYYY",
                  "2000"
               ],
               [
                  "232323",
                  "ZZZZZ",
                  "1999"
               ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"57c6699711bd6a0976cabe8a"
      },
      "ID":"1111",
      "FullName":"BBB",
      "Category":[
         {
            "CategoryId":{
               "$oid":"57c66ebedcba0f63c1ceea51"
            },
            "_id":{
               "$oid":"57e38a8ad190ea1100649798"
            },
            "Value":[
               {
                  "Name":""
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "CategoryId":{
               "$oid":"57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40"
            },
            "_id":{
               "$oid":"57e38a8ad190ea1100649797"
            },
            "Value":[
               [
                  "4444",
                  "XXXX",
                  "2005"
               ],
               [
                  "7777",
                  "GGGG",
                  "2000"
               ],
               [
                  "8888",
                  "ZZZZZ",
                  "1999"
               ]
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here I have an array named 'Category' where it contains objects with different category id.

I need to

1. select a particular category id - '57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40'
2. From the above selected Category, we get 'Value' array
3. From Value array need to find if the second value is equal to 'ZZZZZ' ie. value[1] == 'ZZZZZ'
4. And now, update the matched value arrays with a new value at the end

Eg:

```
[
   "232323",
   "ZZZZZ",
   "1999"
]
should be updated to
    [
   "232323",
   "ZZZZZ",
   "1999",
   "update1"
]

and

[
   "8888",
   "ZZZZZ",
   "1999"
]
should be updated to
[
   "8888",
   "ZZZZZ",
   "1999",
   "update1"
]
```

I have tried as below:

```
resume.update({
        "Category.CategoryId": new ObjectId('57c3df191eb1e59d3959cc43'), 
        "Category.Value.$.1": 'ZZZZZ'
      },
      {"$set": {"Category.Value.$.3": "update1"}
    }, function(err, resData){
        res.send(resData);
    });
```

But, nothing gets updated. Its there any way to get this work. Please help to update the inner array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not possible at the moment since you need to update two positional elements.
There is a JIRA trackable for the sort of behaviour you want here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

It's a problem since you need to match two elements positions:

1. the `Category` element with the matched `CategoryId`
2. the `Value` element in the `Value` array of arrays

If one of these wouldn't be an `array` it would have been possible.

Anyway, Your `update` try above was wrong. **IF** this feature was possible (**and it is not!!!**) it would have been something like this:

```
db.resume.update(
    { 
        Category: {
            $elemMatch: {
                CategoryId: ObjectId('57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40'),
                Value: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        '1': 'ZZZZZ'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $push: {
            'Category.$.Value.$': 'update1'
        }
    }
)
```

The positional `$` operator should be used during the `update` and not the `find` like you did, and it will update the first element that matched the query.
Doing the above will return the error:

> Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'Category.$.Value.$'

Because of the missing feature I explained at the top.
So, currently (version 3.2) you will not be able to do this unless you change your schema.